# How to inform which file or resource fail to fetch in Service Worker addAll

Tags: service-worker, service-worker-events

I need to know how to send to the client which request is failing to be fetched in:

```js
self.addEventListener('install', async ()=>{
    event.waitUntil(caches.open(CACHE_NAME).then((cache)=>
        cache.addAll(urlsToCache)
    ));
});
```

I need to receive It in the client. Something like:

```js
//client.js

var reg=Navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js');
Navigator.serviceWorker.onerror=(ev)=>{
    document.getElementById('err1').textContent = ev.data.message;
}
```

```js
// sw.js
self.addEventListener('install', async (ev)=>{
    event.waitUntil(caches.open(CACHE_NAME).then((cache)=>
        cache.addAll(urlsToCache)
    ).catch((err)=>{
        var client = clients.get(ev.clientId);     // ev does not have clientId
        client.postMessage(err.offendingRequest);  // offendingRequest does not exist
    }));
});
```

Comment: I a not a fan of using addAll because it hides these sorts of issues. Instead I decided to loop through all the assets and put each one in cache directly. That way I can catch the issue and log it.
Otherwise you are just guessing. You can look at the network tab in dev tools to see what request(s) were 404, which can help.

Comment: Here is the trick I used to verify if all the urls are valid or not. We have the urls in "urlsToCache" array. In developer console. I loop through the array using map and use browser fetch method to verify. If any 1 url failed then I get the error in console.
urlsToCache.map(x=> fetch(basedomaiin + x))